# phpspreadsheet взять значение из ячейки в виде текста

Tags: phpspreadsheet

не получается взять значение ячейки как есть при разборе в phpspreadsheed. Цифра заботливо преобразуется из 100,15 в 100.15.
Пробовал так

```
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

и так

```
->rangeToArray(
        'A1:Q11',   // The worksheet range that we want to retrieve
        '',      // Value that should be returned for empty cells
        FALSE,  // Should formulas be calculated (the equivalent of getCalculatedValue() for each cell)
        FALSE,  // Should values be formatted (the equivalent of getFormattedValue() for each cell)
        TRUE    // Should the array be indexed by cell row and cell column
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Получение значение из ячейки происходит с помощью $cell->getValue() или $cekk->getFormattedValue(): https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/accessing-cells/#retrieving-a-cell-value-by-coordinate

В зависимости от локали дробное число может быть представлено как с точкой, так и с запятой.

Ячейка в таблице также может иметь свой тип данных.

Если не получается получить в виде строки, то преобразуйте в строку. Например, с помощью `(string) $value` или еще лучше для этих целей, `number_format()`: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

Comment: нет это совсем не подходит, т.к. phpspreadsheet берёт  значение из ячейки, определяет, что в ячейке число с десятичной ЗАПЯТОЙ и  заменяет эту запятую на нормальную десятичную точку. А мне нужно взять именно число с запятой. И пусть это будет строка

Comment: откройте документ и посмотрите какой тип ячейки. если число, то измените на строку и посмотрите что будет при парсинге. Если результат будет нужная вам строка, то попробуйте изменить формат ячейки setDataType() (типы в PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType), а затем извлечь значение.

Comment: Ну вероятно не имеет смысла. Во-первых, фактически требуется перезаписать с  
DataTypeDataType::TYPE_STRING (хотя, возможно в объект попадёт текст, а потом возьмётся текст). Во-вторых, я беру массив строк, не очень хочется пробегать по каждой ячейке и устанавливать тип. Самое интересное, что с двумя и более знаками после запятой, парсер берёт текст. Явно что-то не так в механизме пересчёта формул и/или форматировании.